# Problema con vista CSS en sub carpetas handlebars

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, mongodb

escribo por que tengo un problema intentando hacer una pagina web con js. El problema consiste en que toda la vista CSS se logra ver en las vistas.hbs que se encuentran en la carpeta principal "views", sin embargo, si hago otras vistas .hbs en subcarpetas de la carpeta "views", no se logra apreciar la vista CSS.

[image: El orden de carpetas es el siguiente:]

Entonces por ejemplo las vistas about, contactos, home y servicios, tienen correcta la vista con CSS, y para las vistas que se encuentran dentro de users, es posible conectar la ruta sin problemas, pero no absorve la configuración de CSS.

¿Me podrían indicar donde se puede configurar eso?.

La carpeta views, la tengo configurada de la siguiente manera:

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({

```
defaultLayout: 'main',
layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'partials'),
extname: '.hbs'
```

}));

app.set('view engine', '.hbs'); //Handlebars

Resumen: las rutas están correctamente conectadas, el único problema, es de vista CSS de sub carpetas en views.

Comment: ¿Podrías ver la consola del navegador para ver los posibles mensajes de erro? Hace falta ver también cómo enlazas los archivos de hojas de estilos (css). Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio, al abrir la consola me has iluminado y he detectado el error finalmente. simplemente a la ruta donde referenciaba el stilo de CSS debía agregar un "../". Por ejemplo en vez de "assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js", puse "../assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js".

Answer (score 0):

gracias por tu respuesta. Sabes que justamente al revisar la consola del navegador he notado que al acceder a las rutas donde justamente no veo las vistas de CSS me da errores que mencionan no encontrar dichas direcciones.

[image: Va la foto:]

En cuanto a como referencio los archivos de estilos va acá:

```
<!-- Favicons -->
    <link href="img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
    <link href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Muli:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i"
        rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
    <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/icofont/icofont.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/venobox/venobox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Template Main CSS File -->
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Acabo de notar también que en mis carpetas tengo dos carpetas vendor, creo que al parecer podría ser ese un problema:

[image]